# React Router links needed to be reloaded but URL changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React and I doing a project on the same....however I faced an issue with the routing of the links given in the navbar.

This is my linking given in the navbar

```
import React, { Component, usestate } from "react"

import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

Sport Head from "./Head"

import "./header.css"

const Header () => {

const [click, setclick] = useState(false)

return (

<>

<Head />

<header>

<nav className='flexSB'>

<ul className=(click? "mobile-nav": "flexSB ") onClick=(() => setClick(false))>

<li>

<Link to='/'>Home</Link>

</li>

<li>

<Link to='/courses'>Courses</Link>

</li>

<li>

<Link to='/about'>About</Link>

</li>

<li>

<Link to='/team'>Team</Link>

</li>

<li>

<Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>

</li>

<li>

<Link to='/login'>Login</Link>

</li>

</ul>

<div className='start'>
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css"

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"

import About from "./components/about/About"

import CourseHome from "./components/allcourses/CourseHome"

import Team from "./components/team/Team"

import Contact from "./components/contact/Contact"

import Home from "./components/home/Home"

import SignIn from "./components/login/Login"

function App() {

return (

<>

<Router>

<Switch>

<Route exact path='/' component=[Home] />

<Route exact path='/about' component=(About) />

<Route exact path='/courses' component=(CourseHome />

<Route exact path='/team component(Team] />

<Route exact path='/contact' component=(Contact) />

<Route path="/login' component={SignIn] />

</Switch>

</Router>

</>

}

export default App
```

Here I guess I did the code correctly..I tried doing different methods but still I am not getting the desired result.

Whenever I click on a link, the url changes however the page needs to be reloaded each time to get redirected to the respective page...

Comment: there are errors in the code

Answer (score -1):

First you should correct the syntax errors. (or it seems broken for some reason.)

```
// useState instead of usestate
import React, { Component, useState } from "react"
```

```
// Add '=' before parentheses
const Header = () => {}
```

```
// In Route, component={YourComponent}, not () or []
// And make sure to close them
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
```